# PHP Links to Local File on MAC & PC

Tags: php

**complete** Novice to PHP and HTML so this could be a schoolboy error. I'm trying to set up a small Intranet site for my work. I want to be able to display links to Local Files Eg Comapny Handbooks, Procedures etc. My main issue is that it needs to be both PC and MAC user friendly (Mac users mainly use Firefox, PC's use IE).I have a PHP script on each page that I can get to work individually for a Mac or a PC but can't get it working simultaneously. Eg I'd like my code to look up the users OS and the run the part of the script relevant to displaying the Local File link for that OS. I believe the critical part of the script is the 'file///' If it's 'file///' it works on a PC in IE & Firefox but it needs to be 'File' (without three /'s) to work on a Mac? but I may be wrong in that analogy. Current code as follows;

```
<?php

//determine OS of user MAC or PC
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT"); 
if (strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE) 
$os = "Windows"; 
else if((strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE) || (strpos($user_agent, "PPC") !== FALSE))
$os = "Mac";

if ($os == "Windows") 
{
//path to S:\One reality\Personnel\Culture & Values
$uncpath = "//servername/shared/one reality/personnel/culture & values/";

//get all files with a .pdf extension.
$files = glob($uncpath . "*.pdf");

//print each file name
foreach ($files as $file)

{
    echo "<a target=_blank href='file:///$file'>".preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "",basename($file))."</a><br><br>"; 
}
}
elseif ($os == "Mac")
{
//path to S:\One reality\Personnel\Culture & Values
$uncpath = "//servername/shared/one reality/personnel/culture & values/";

//get all files with a .pdf extension.
$files = glob($uncpath . "*.pdf");

//print each file name
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo "<a target=_blank href='file:$file'>".preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "",basename($file))."</a><br><br>"; 
}
}

?>
```

The above code runs fine on a PC and opens a new TAB as a pdf but on a Mac the code does not get round to running the Mac specific 'file:' without the three slashes and as a result does not know how to display the Local file link. PS I know about allowing local file links in Firefox and that is in place so it's basically a coding issue. I suspect its something wrong within my IF $os = statement.

I'm preapred to scrap this approach and start again if you think I've gone down the wrong route.

Comment: I am no mac user but, can't you echo links like on [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568) page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for detect Os you can use the "USER AGENT" in php... IF you want , you can read [this article](http://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://sebastienguillon.com/journal/2005/10/script-php-pour-dechiffrer-les-chaines-user-agent&act=urlz), with a script detect os, browser, all details in the user agent....

For your problem in your "else", have you try to create log in your "else" part ?

```
elseif ($os == "Mac")
{
    print_r("mac os was found");
    // your code
}
```

For your code, if/else is not very important, you can do that :

```
<?php
    // First step: you detect OS plateform : 

    //determine OS of user MAC or PC and add "pathOsFile" var:
    $user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT"); 
    if (strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE){
        $os = "Windows"; 
        $pathOsFile = "file:///";
    }else if((strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE) || (strpos($user_agent, "PPC") !== FALSE)){
        $os = "Mac";
        $pathOsFile = "file:":
    }

    // Second step: You display all your file...

    //path to S:\One reality\Personnel\Culture & Values
    $uncpath = "//servername/shared/one reality/personnel/culture & values/";

    //get all files with a .pdf extension.
    $files = glob($uncpath . "*.pdf");

    //print each file name
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        echo "<a target=_blank href='".$pathOsFile.$file."'>".preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "",basename($file))."</a><br><br>"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but the OS detection is working fine, it's the IF 'Windows' or IF 'Mac' then do etc... part of the statement that I need help.

Comment: To reiterate, I have no problem obtaining the user OS, I can prove this by simply echo the $os which is 'Windows' on a PC & 'Mac' on a Mac. My problem is how the code then deals with that discovery - Eg If $os=Mac go off and do this but if $os=Windows go off and do that instead? I hope that makes sense.. ? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not speak currenty english, You want just :
    - detect your os ( it's okay for you, I know).
    - and display your list file with "file:///$yourpathfile" for Microsoft and "file:$yourpathfile" for MAC ? it's that?

Comment: Okay, I have edit my answer, you can also use a function in your if/else for make your treatment, but it's not optimize... whith this method, on first, you detect your os, and create a pathFile for windows "file:///" or other "file:" and after, you make your treatment for all OS... they are not duplicate code. All code for display your file is in the same place.

Comment: Thank you ever so much @Doc Roms - your code worked like a charm.